# Laravel 4 Blade {{}} and Hogan.js {{}} Syntax

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-4, hogan.js

**I am using Laravel 4 with the Blade Templating Engine and Hogan.js.**

By default my site thinks `{{...}}` is used by PHP and Laravel. Now I want to use Hogan.js and the syntax is `{{...}}` too. I am getting an error, because they use the same syntax here.

How can I use both?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can prepend `@` to your Hogan placeholders, and Laravel will ignore them.

```
// This will work only in JavaScript
@{{ JavaScript }}

// This will be rendered in blade
{{ $foo }}
```